# UV Map not showing in UV/Image Editor

Tags: uv

I was trying to make a uv map test for my guitar so i hit smart uv map just to see how is all going but it wont apear in the uv/image editor, i tried making some seams but nothing. I made some uv maps before and they always appeared in the uv/image editor
[image]

Comment: Maybe clear that Render Result there and see if they show up then, as well as zoom out and make sure they aren't appearing outside the image area which is possible if they were moved by accident.

Comment: Yep Render Result will not show uv mapping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UV map does not show up in the render preview, open a new image in the UV editor, or create one.

Comment: Old question but I had this same issue and in my case it was that in uv editor I had accidentally turned on "UV local view" in uv editor window View>UV local view. Since this is the first answer that comes up in google I thought it was useful to share this as possible solution if someone else has this issue.

Comment: I just encountered this issue, and took some screenshots to further illustrate the issue/fix. Here's the issue https://imgur.com/s697jhN and here's a blowup of what to click to fix it https://imgur.com/EQQyOGA