# Object not visible in uv editor

Tags: uv-image-editor

I modelled a character but in the uv editor only the gun in the holster seems not the other objects.I dont know whats the problem.

[image: just the gun seems]

Comment: The question is unclear, could you please be more specific.

Comment: Do you mean that the gun and the holster aren't separate objects?

Comment: in the scene there is also a human character with belt,boots,holster and gun etc... but there occure something that when i get to uv editor only the gun seems in the ground

Comment: Just want to link to this other thread in case someone else also finds this current question on google but is actually having this other issue (ie. window set to Render preview) https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/106013/uv-map-not-showing-in-uv-image-editor

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are working in **Local** viewport.

[image]

You can swith from **Local** viewport to standard viewport and viceversa by pressing "/" key (on the numpad, or **Shift+7**). This will affect also the UV/Image editor (you can see the UVs only for the objects you see in local viewport).

The local viewport mode is useful because you can see only the selected objects, but you don't have to hide the other objects in the scene. Just select your object(s), press "/" and you see only them. Press "/" again and you will see all objects in the scene.

Comment: omg im so stupid :d i also use it to solitude the object to work easy but i didnt aware of it. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

It seems very strange, that the "visible layers" panel is not on your screenshot. It should be directly right of the Global dropdown at the bottom right of your screen.

Unless you did hide the rest of the model by pressing H (undo via alt+H), you might have different parts of your model placed on different layers. You can make all those layers visible by using the visible layer panel or pressing 1,2,3,4,5,6,... on your keyboard to switch between those layers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you haven't deleted it on accident? Hitting X on your keyboard deletes the selected object. Look at the outliner panel to see if it's still in the scene.

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter **Edit mode**. UV maps are not visible in Object mode